# Symfony 2 and custom session variables from legacy application

Tags: php, symfony, session

I'm in the process of setting up the ability to migrate from a Legacy codebase to a Symfony one, and I'm trying to share legacy session variables between the two applications.

I can currently `var_dump($_SESSION)` in `app_dev.php` and the `user_id` key comes through from the legacy application. However, when I run the following in a controller, I don't get any session variables:

```
var_dump($request->getSession()->all());
```

**So to clarify**, I currently have access to `$_SESSION['user_id']`, so the session is shared between applications successfully, but the Symfony session object and it's parameter bags do not contain the legacy keys.

My goal:

- For the `user_id` key to be available in the `$request->getSession()` call
- For all other keys to be available here

My problems:

I have tried the [PHP Session bridge](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/php_bridge.html) but I don't think this is supposed to do what I want it to. Not only does adding the bridge parameter not do anything in my Symfony application, but from what I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28160980/736809) this is meant to be used somehow in *the other* legacy application, not in Symfony.

> Symfony sessions store data like attributes in special 'Bags' which use a key in the $_SESSION superglobal. This means that a Symfony session cannot access arbitrary keys in $_SESSION that may be set by the legacy application, although all the $_SESSION contents will be saved when the session is saved. *[From [Integrating with legacy sessions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_php_bridge.html)]*

I've also taken a look at [TheodoEvolutionSessionBundle](https://github.com/theodo/TheodoEvolutionSessionBundle), but this is old, isn't actively supported or worked on and doesn't work with Symfony 3.

I have noticed that Symfony stores it's session data under `$_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']`, so my initial thought was to do this in `app_dev.php`:

```
$_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['user_id'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

This is *clearly* the wrong way to do this, as I also have to call `session_start()` in there as well.

**How can I migrate legacy $_SESSION data into Symfony's Session object?** Is there something built-in to Symfony to help with this or a bundle available? If there isn't, *where* can I place my custom `$_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']` 'hack' in the correct place to handle the migration of all these keys?

Comment: There is a newer answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38669383/symfony-legacy-session-issues-porting-a-massive-project-slowly

Comment: Nice, thanks! That should go in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony introduces a concept of session bags into the session, so everything is namespaced. There's no build in solution to access non-namespaced session attributes.

The solution is to use scalar bags, just like [TheodoEvolutionSessionBundle](https://github.com/theodo/TheodoEvolutionSessionBundle/) does. I wouldn't use it directly, but implement something custom that will work for you project (they only provide integrations for symfony1 and codeigniter anyway). Base it on their idea, but adapt it to your needs.

Alternatively, you could implement a `kernel.request` listener that would rewrite legacy session attributes to the Symfony one:

```php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $event->getRequest()->getSession()->set('user_id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
}
```

**Jim's edit**

I created an event listener on `kernel.request` - every request that comes in, we loop through all the legacy session vars in `$_SESSION` and place them in Symfony's session bag. Here's the listener:

```php
namespace AppBundle\Session;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\NamespacedAttributeBag,
    Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface,
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent,
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class LegacySessionHandler implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string The name of the bag name containing all the brunel values
     */
    const LEGACY_SESSION_BAG_NAME = 'old_app';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'onKernelRequest'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Transfer all the legacy session variables into a session bag, so $_SESSION['user_id'] will be accessible
     * via $session->getBag('old_app')->get('user_id'). The first bag name is defined as the class constant above
     *
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        /** There might not be a session, in the case of the profiler / wdt (_profiler, _wdt) **/
        if (!isset($_SESSION))
        {
            return;
        }

        $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();

        /** Only create the old_app bag if it doesn't already exist **/
        try
        {
            $bag = $session->getBag(self::LEGACY_SESSION_BAG_NAME);
        }
        catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e)
        {
            $bag = new NamespacedAttributeBag(self::LEGACY_SESSION_BAG_NAME);
            $bag->setName(self::LEGACY_SESSION_BAG_NAME);
            $session->registerBag($bag);
        }

        foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value)
        {
            /** Symfony prefixes default session vars with an underscore thankfully, so ignore these **/
            if (substr($key, 0, 1) === '_' && $key !== self::LEGACY_SESSION_BAG_NAME)
            {
                continue;
            }

            $bag->set($key, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

As explained in the comments below, this isn't necessarily the best way of doing this. But it works.

Comment: The latter option seems simple, are there any downsides to that? How about looping through all non-symfony session values and, if they don't already exist in the Symfony session, setting them in the listener? Will it work with n-dimensional arrays as well as scalars (so, any value basically)?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. The drawback is it's harder to test as it uses globals. Also, it will always trigger the session start. In past I went with the first option and it worked like a charm!

Comment: I ended up doing this and, apart from testability being affected, it seems to work okay: https://3v4l.org/rZqKs

Comment: Testability is one thing. Other thing is that if you change values in Symfony, they won't be available in the legacy app. First solution works both ways. Accept the answer if it helped you please ;)

Comment: Values only go one way as in legacy -> Symfony so it'll be good. Happy to accept, you okay with me pasting in my result as per your suggestion?

Comment: I'm not completely sure this works anymore: `Cannot register a bag when the session is already started.` (Symfony 3.1.2).   
`
session.legacy:
    class: AppBundle\Session\LegacySessionHandler
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
`

Answer (score 1):

Is there any complicated life-cycle for your session variables? Or they are mainly read-only once you're logged in into your application?

If the latter applies, you might be able to add that "hack" into an event subscriber. This subscriber would listen for the [Interactive Login Event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#security-events), and it could look something like:

```
class PortSessionHandler implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session) {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => [
                ['portLegacySession']
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function portLegacySession(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        //here you could populate SF2 session with legacy session
        $this->session->set('user_id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your example, I registered a listener on the `kernel.request` event and looped through all non-symfony vars to set them in a new parameter bag.