# Symfony custom authentication provider log out on request overlap

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

This problem has been reproduced with Symfony 3.3.17 and 3.4.9

I have a custom authenticaton provider that ties together a legacy application and a Symfony application:

**app/config/security.yml**

```
security:
    providers:
        zog:
            id: app.zog_user_provider


    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:

            anonymous: ~
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - app.legacy_token_authenticator
                    - app.token_authenticator
                entry_point: app.legacy_token_authenticator
```

**src/AppBundle/Security/LegacyTokenAuthenticator:**

```
class LegacyTokenAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    private $session;

    private $router;

    public function __construct(
        RouterInterface $router,
        SessionInterface $session,
        $environment
    ) {
        if (session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
            if ($environment != 'test'){
                session_start();
            }
            $session->start();
            $this->setSession($session);
        }
        //if (!$session->isStarted()) {

        //}


        $this->router = $router;
    }


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSession()
    {
        return $this->session;
    }


    /**
     * @param mixed $session
     */
    public function setSession($session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }


    /**
     * Called on every request. Return whatever credentials you want,
     * or null to stop authentication.
     */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $this->getSession();

        if (isset($_SESSION['ADMIN_logged_in']) && intval($_SESSION['ADMIN_logged_in'])){
            return $_SESSION['ADMIN_logged_in'];
        }
        return;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        return $userProvider->loadUserByUserId($credentials);
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $user->getUsername() == $credentials;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication is needed, but it's not sent
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('app_security_login');
        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**src/AppBundle/Security/TokenAuthenticator:**

```
class TokenAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{

    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * Default message for authentication failure.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $failMessage = 'Invalid credentials';

    /**
     * @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface
     */
    private $passwordEncoder;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of FormAuthenticator
     */
    public function __construct(
        RouterInterface $router,
        SessionInterface $session,
        $environment,
        UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
    ) {
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
        $this->router = $router;

        if (session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
            if ($environment != 'test') {
                session_start();
            }
            $session->start();
        }

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->getPathInfo() != '/security/login' || !$request->isMethod('POST')) {
            return;
        }

        return ['username' => $request->request->get('username'), 'password' => $request->request->get('password')];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        try {
            return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials['username']);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException(
                $e->getMessage() != '' ?$e->getMessage():$this->failMessage
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        if ($this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password'])) {
            return true;
        }
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException($this->failMessage);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        $_SESSION['ADMIN_logged_in'] = $token->getUser()->getUsername();
        if ($_SESSION['legacy_page_requested'] ?? '/'){
            $url = $_SESSION['legacy_page_requested'] ?? '/';
        }else{
            $url = '/workflow_detailv2view.php';
        }
        unset($_SESSION['legacy_page_requested']);
        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        $request->getSession()->set(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception);

        $url = $this->router->generate('app_security_login');
        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('app_security_login');
        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I find is that this system works fine. However a new feature in a legacy page is running 2 Symfony async application requests which are overlapping.

In this case what happens is the 1st request shows 2 Session Cookie

```
Request URL: https://somedomain.com/system/staff_meeting/edit/1
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 222.154.225.22:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 13 Jun 2018 21:57:19 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=90
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mpm-itk/2.4.7-04 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.0.20
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=tn7jhi5n2iu16le1os971vn024; path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.20
```

and the second request is being logged out:

```
Request URL: https://somedomain.com/system/staff_meeting/edit/1
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: 222.154.225.22:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 332
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 14 Jun 2018 01:26:43 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=90
Location: /system/security/login
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mpm-itk/2.4.7-04 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.0.20
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.20
```

I believe this must be some race condition in accessing the $_SESSION variable we use to hold together legacy system and Symfony application.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: For session management in Symfony, better use either $request->getSession() or use dependency injection and inject SessionInterface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the following changes to your authenticators to keep the session management to symfony:

src/AppBundle/Security/LegacyTokenAuthenticator:

```
public function __construct(RouterInterface $router) {
    $this->router = $router;
}

public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials);
}

public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    if ($session->has('ADMIN_logged_in') && intval($session->get('ADMIN_logged_in'))){
        return $session->get('ADMIN_logged_in');
    }
    return null;
}
```

src/AppBundle/Security/TokenAuthenticator:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $session->set('ADMIN_logged_in', $token->getUser()->getUsername());
    if ($session->has('legacy_page_requested')) {
        $url = $session->get('legacy_page_requested') ?? '/';
        $session->remove('legacy_page_requested');
    } else {
        $url = '/workflow_detailv2view.php';
    }
    return new RedirectResponse($url);
}
```

Comment: So with this solution, I can't see how the legacy application checks that someone has logged in on the Symfony side, as there is nothing in $_SESSION. The login page is only present in Symfony

Comment: check the listener proposed in this solution for sharing session variables across platforms: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601629/symfony-2-and-custom-session-variables-from-legacy-application

Answer (score 1):

I was able to circumvent the problem by setting

security.yml

```
security:
    session_fixation_strategy: none
```

I am not sure however how the regeneration of the session and corresponding renaming of Cookie value can be fixed.

I'm still keen to hear other thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your architecture but I think it is best if you do not have two Guard Authenticators on a single firewall.

You can make your Symfony session a legacy session like so:

```
# config.yml
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: "/tmp/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
```

From there, any legacy session you have should be manageable using the `$_SESSION` superglobal (which legacy code often uses).

If you want to have different log-in rules for legacy and for your new system, my recommendation would be to set up two different firewalls. You can assign a [shared context](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context) so a user doesn't need to re-authenticate, and simply add some additional rules in a child class.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid to call session_start() or $session->start();! Symfony will do this itself.

Comment: Is this an answer? Session restarts on authentication success.

Comment: The extra session_starts could initiate the issue. I never care of starting the session, its worth trying.

Comment: Could be. But as he works with guardAuthenticator, session gets managed automatically. 

I had problem where session variables which I set before on auth success, got lost here.